# Root LG G3 D855 5.0 Lollipop with a Mac

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, macos, lg-g3

I have been trying to root my LG G3 (D855) with Android 5.0 using my Mac Book Pro and so far I haven't been able to find a working method.

I followed [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93437/how-can-i-root-lg-g3) guide, but it seems that the combination of Android Version + Hardware Version of my phone isn't compatible with the vulnerability.

I also tried [guide-root-lg-firmwares-kitkat-lollipop](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/guide-root-lg-firmwares-kitkat-lollipop-t3056951) One Click root option, but it requires Windows...

Do you guys have any suggestions? I even tried to downgrade to Android 4.2.2, but I couldn't find a Mac guide for that either....

Any help is appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to Downgrade the version of the phone's firmware,You just need an working method to root your device, Since all the "One-Click-Script" ways doesn't work for you, We'll go the Classic way, Just follow this guide,

Download the ROOT package from [HERE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3351692&d=1433643908)

> 1. **Enable ADB debugging**
>
>    1. Go to Settings > About Phone > Software Information and tap build  number until you are presented with "You are now a developer".
>    2. Back to Settings screen.
>    3. In Developer Options, enable USB Debugging.
> 2. **Insert the USB cable**
> 3. **Send the required files to the device using this command**
>
>    - adb.exe push busybox /data/local/tmp && adb.exe push
>        UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip /data/local/tmp
>    - [image]
> 4. **Go to Download Mode**
>
>    1. Disconnect the USB cable.
>    2. Power off the device.
>    3. Hold volume up and insert the USB cable.
> 5. **Find which COM port your device is connected**
>
>    1. Run ports.bat
>    2. From the output see what ports your phone connected to
>
>       - [image]
> 6. **Run the root installer script**
>
>    - Send_Command.exe \.\COMx < root
>    - Send_Command.exe \.\COMx < reboot
>    - *Change the COMx with the correct port number of the DIAG port.*
>        *and the output should be like this* [image]

I'm not a MAC guy, So i don't know for sure if you can do that on your MBP, But i know that you can use VirtualBox to install Windows inside your MBP as described [HERE](http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/25/install-run-windows-10-mac-virtualbox-os-x/).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did a lot of progress with this but I am stuck at the `Send_Command` part, of course the exe file is not executable on my MBP.

I tried putting the phone in both Download and Recovery Mode and tried to start an `adb shell` session, but the phone is not seen by my computer while in any of those modes. I also tried to start a serial connection with it, but I can't see the phone in the `/dev/tty.*` list..

Any suggestions?

Comment: I got the  Serial Communication to work after installing the LG G3 Drivers and LG Suite on my MBP, but there are two problems now, although I can see the phone as `cu.lgusbserial1412` in the `/dev/` folder, I can't send commands to it... I have tried `screen` and the Mac Os app [Serial](https://www.decisivetactics.com/) but although they connect I cant seem to be able to send  commands...
The second problem is that when the phone is in recovery or download mode I can't even see the phone listed.. At this point I give up, I have spent over 5 hours on the problem without progress..

Comment: This guide is for Windows not Mac.